# How can the universe be flat and have no center if universal mass-energy content is finite?

Tags: cosmology, curvature

WMAP measurements confirm that the universe is flat within a 0.4% margin of error.  If we assume the universe is flat and there is no 'center' then how could the mass energy content be finite since that would imply a cosmic boundary? (Boundaries define the location of the 'center')

*Let me be clear, I am not stating that there is an infinite mass energy content in the universe, I am simply taking advantage of the fact that the quantity of mass-energy content in our universe is still an open question.

Comment: eg a torus is a closed manifold (ie compact without boundary) and can be flat

Answer (score 1):

When cosmologists say that "the universe is flat" they actually mean the "observable universe." This doesn't imply that the universe as a whole is flat, just that the observable universe is very small in relation to any curvature.

Comment: Well... If the principle of equivalence is valid then  we must assign a mean local curvature because of universal expansion.  I understand how cosmologists retrieved a 0.4% margin of error (from CMB) but in my understanding it doesn't correlate with universal expansion.

Comment: @SpacetimeEngineer Imagine that in my answer the "very small" is replaced with "**extremely** small". Basically the smaller the observable part is, the closer to flat it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Can you name the source that gave a finite estimate for the mass/energy content of the "universe" so we can look at the context? I would assume they were probably talking about the [observable universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe), defined to mean only the points in space close enough so that a light wave (or gravitational wave) emitted from that point at any moment after the Big Bang would have had time to reach us by the present. According to current estimates, "close enough" would correspond to a [comoving distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance) of about 47 billion light years or less.

Comment: Forgive me if my question was misleading I will be sure to re-word it for the sake of minimizing confusion but I never stated that the universe actually contained a finite mass-energy content.  I only asked how could it have a finite mass energy content if there was no center and we assumed it to be flat?  Also I was not speaking about the observable universe necessarily and I wasn't referring to any sort of ambient space which may contain our universe.  I was only referring to both observable mass energy content and the kind which may exist beyond the cosmological horizon.

Comment: @SpacetimeEngineer - But what prompted you to ask the question "how could the mass energy content be finite"? Did you see anyone *claim* it would be finite, or are you just asking if there's any conceivable way it could be? (If the latter, consider the possibility it could have an [unusual topology](http://plus.maths.org/content/space-do-all-roads-lead-home).)

Comment: To be clear, I don't assume the mass energy content of the universe is finite or infinite. I am only trying to extract information by means of simple reasoning. To answer you question though, (part of) what I was asking if it was conceivable that the mass-energy content in the universe could be finite if the rest were true. I found the question to be both reasonable, valid and non-trivial but if you disagree, please state why. Otherwise thank you for your input, I will check out your unusual topology link.

Comment: I don't object to the question, just found the wording a little odd--as an analogy it'd be like asking "how can cats and dogs have similar brain sizes if cats are so much more intelligent than dogs?" The phrasing makes it sound like there's widespread belief that cats are much more intelligent, rather than it just being a random what-if question about whether it's remotely possible they *could* be more intelligent, without saying there's any evidence or other reason to believe it.

Comment: @ Hypnosifl Oh yes I understand, apologies. I am defiantly an odd ball when it comes to asking questions but for what it's worth there is a deeply rooted and genuine motivation to the question.